# Matchings in a Graph proof

Tags: graph-theory

Let M be a matching in an graph G. Prove that if P is an alternating path
for M in G that begins and ends at unmatched vertices, then the matching M′
obtained from M by replacing the edges of M that lie in P with the edges of P
not in M, is a matching of G with one more edge than M.

I am really struggling with this proof, can someone please show me how this proof is done

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume there are currently $m$ edges in $M$. Thus, there must be $2m+2$ vertices in $P$ (all vertices of the $m$ edges and $2$ unmatched vertices). Thus, there must be $2m+1$ edges in $P$ and each edge connects two vertices from different parts of the graph (by definition of alternating path). Now, consider $M'$. $M' = P-M$. Now, we need to show that no two edges in $M'$ have a common vertex (for it to be actually a matching). It's straightforward, as of the $2m+2$ vertices, $2$ are new vertices and the rest $2m$ were already a part of another matching (hence can't possible contain a repetition). Thus, $M'$ is also a matching. The number of edges in $M'$ are $2m+1$(total edges in $P$) - $m$(total edges in $M$) = $m+1$.